# simulating a CAN / OBD2 vehicle using python-can

Tags: python, can-bus, obd-ii

I wrote a front-end demo app that simulates access and display of vehicle data. I'd like to extend my demo to access a simulated vehicle CAN-bus / OBD to have my demo retrieve standard and non-standard -- custom specified -- vehicle data.

I hoping to retrieve that data via web sockets.

Can Python-Can be used to create a simulated vehicle with standard and custom PIDs that my front-end could then access via Websockets - CAN-Sockets.

thank you,

Dan